# How to filter collections in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm new in Rails, and I'm trying to filter the animals I have on my DB, by one of their properties. I have read that I can make it by a scope in the controller, and have access to it by a parameter on the URL, but I think that doesn't work for me because I'm using a loop to create my HTML.

Is there a way to add a filter to the collection I'm using (@animals)?

```
<% @animals.each do |animal| %>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <%=link_to animal.ncommon, animal %>
    </a>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

I hope I was clear with my question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I can make it by a scope in the controller..."...?

Comment: the scope i was referring to, is what sameera207 commented below. He just correct me that the scope must be in the model, not in te controller.

Answer (score 0):

So the best practice is to move the `scope` to the models , not in the controller. Here is and example. (please note that this may change depending on your file structure and names).

here I'm going to filter animals by type. Lets say type 1 and type 2.

```
#model app/models/animal.rb
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_type, -> (ty) { where(type: ty) }
end

#controller app/controllers/animals_controller.rb

class AnimalsController < ApplicationController
  ... other code

  def index
    # calls the by_type method/scope in the Animal model
    # filter the records and assignes them to @animals varaible
    @animals = Animal.by_type(params[:type])
  end

  ... other code 
end
```

then you can use your loop in the view. When you want to filter, you call the index action with a parameter

E.g `http://localhost:3000/animals?type=1`

So the idea is, not to filter inside the loop, but to get the filtered results to the `@animals` variable.

Comment: Thank you! this will help me for another similar task that i have to do, but i just found another solution that i can use in the loop i was talking. i will post it in another comment. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution that i can use in the loop.
I changed:

```
<% @animals.each do |animal| %>
```

to:

```
<% @animals.where("promo > ?", 0).each do |animal| %>
```

Here i´m getting all the animals that has a promo greater than zero.
Thanks!

Comment: hey @chavez, while your solution works fine, please note that having ActiveRecord queries in the view consider as a code smell. :)